# Upgrade from networkx 2.4 to networkx 2.2

Tags: networkx

I would like to upgrade from "networkx 2.4" to "networkx 2.2". How to do this using python's pip command? Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't moving from 2.4 to 2.2 be a downgrade, not an upgrade?

Comment: Yes, a downgrade. I would like to upgrade to an older version.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a specific version with the `==` operator. `pip` should automatically uninstall the current version you have installed and install the older version:

```
pip install networkx==2.2
```